# Detect when iPad's screen is off or Home button is pressed event in Unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

How do I write a function which detects when iPad's screen is off/power button is pressed and also when home button is pressed? 
I know `OnApplicationFocus()` and `OnApplicationPause()` functions but they run only when I press Power button on the iPad when `Run in Background is set to suspend`, and when `Run in Background is set to exit`, these functions stop working when power button is pressed. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnApplicationQuit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html).

From the manual:

> Note: iOS applications are usually suspended and do not quit. You
>   should tick "Exit on Suspend" in Player settings for iOS builds to
>   cause the game to quit and not suspend, otherwise you may not see this
>   call. If "Exit on Suspend" is not ticked then you will see calls to
>   OnApplicationPause instead.